# How to create a User search view?

Tags: 7, views, users

I am trying to create User search view (using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)). But when I create the view, I am not able to see the search option in filter.

What I am missing?

Comment: The above question is too vague to be answerable. What do you want to do? Are you sure **Views** is the correct tool for doing it? How do you create a View? What do you expect to see in the search option in filter?

Comment: It is very simple question...I want to search User search result using views....

Comment: I do not want to use exposed filter for this...I want to use global search form...and drupal search url for showing the result...

Comment: I agree with @FreeRadical you have to provide much more info, including what you have done so far to try and resolve this...

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this is more than you are looking for, or it is difficult to follow. Drupal's built-in search is bad for a number of reasons. One of them is how poorly it handles partial matches (i.e. 'appl' for 'apple'). Generally, search is done best when you use the search API module and integrate it with a search server. If you start down the path of looking into this you will find a lot of people saying you need to use SOLR, which is not the case. SOLR is great for more intensive applications, but you can make a very effective search system without it. This article details how:
https://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-1-how-create-search-pages

Following those instructions you will want to create an index of users. Then you will need to use the search views modules to create a view of the search results. The exposed filters (your search box is an exposed filter in this case) can even be placed in separate blocks.
This article describes that portion of the process:
https://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/how-create-search-pages-using-views-drupal-7

This may be a little more work than you hoped for, but it will solve the problem.

Comment: Above articles not found useful to me...I am very clear..I am looking for search filter for User View. When choose user view...It does not show me Search option in filter...Do you know that

Comment: I'm not sure if the filter you are looking for exists the way you want it to. A more modest start is this: In your user view create a filter on the user name and expose the filter. You will now have an autocomplete filter that will search by user names. It will also show a list of users. If that is not desired you can work around the behaviour by also adding the user id filter and making it match uid of -1 BUT using the OR operator between the two. That will give you a simple autocomplete search field. But a real 'search' sytstem requires the method posted above.

Comment: I am trying to use the global search form and their result page for user search. sitename.com/search/user/rony - this will be my sample result page...but instead of normal result. I am trying to show user result using panel and views module.....